# Tensorflow's decode_csv only reading one line

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I get the `decode_csv` function to read every line in my CSV?

I'm currently trying to load data from my CSV file onto my GPU. Data loads fine onto the GPU, except... only one line of my 640-line CSV file is actually read. Where do you think I'm going wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['dataset.csv'])
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    record_defaults = [['']]*121
    all_columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)) as sess:
        # Start populating the filename queue.
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        # Iterate through all the columns
        vals = []
        for x in range(121):
            tmp = all_columns.pop()
            myval = tmp.eval(session=sess)
            vals.append(myval)

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

Then if I do...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> vals = np.asarray(vals)
>>> vals.shape
(121,)
```

I do have 121 columns per each of the 640 rows in my CSV. The values in `vals` look fine to me, except I'm not actually getting all 640 lines read. I'm guessing it has to do with:

```
all_columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm. Figured it out.

Apparently there is a difference between `sess.run()` and `pop()` in terms of how we extract row data.

I happen to have 640 lines in my CSV file and 121 columns, hence the:

```
record_defaults = [['']]*121
```

and

```
for x in range(640):
```

Note that this is mostly hardcoded just for testing purposes. Solution below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['../Datasets/CMU_face_images_dataset.csv'])
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    record_defaults = [['']]*121
    all_columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

    # TWO NEW LINES
    name = all_columns[0]
    data = all_columns[1:]

    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)) as sess:
        # Start populating the filename queue.
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        vals = []
        names = []
        for x in range(640):

            # THIS IS THE NEW LINE
            _name, _val = sess.run([name, data])

            # OLD LINES
            # tmp = all_columns.pop()
            # myval = tmp.eval(session=sess)
            # vals.append(myval)

            names.append(_name)
            vals.append(_val)

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```